# Use generics in databinding's xml

Tags: android-databinding

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.ihu.intelligentmedicinechest.activity.MainActivity">

    <data>

    <variable
        name="items"
        type="java.util.Collection&lt;? extends com.ihu.intelligentmedicinechest.adapter.binder.ItemBinder&gt;"/>

    </data>
</layout>
```

Use generics in data binding XML is wrong. Follow is the exception:

android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding errors.
  ****/ data binding error ****msg:cannot find type argument for ?extendscom.tvvbbb.adapter.binder.ItemBinder in java.util.Collection

loc:56:30 - 56:34
  ****\ data binding error ****

How can I process it?

Comment: I could use such generics by using `Object` as `type` - of course this method has many restrictions and will be highlighted as an error.